# How to remove an error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token S in JSON at position 0"?

Tags: php, json, ajax

I referenced sols of SO, but nothing solve the error.

I have a file `dashboard.html` with search condition and on click it calls `loadtable.js` and this `loadtable.js` file using `search.php` retrives rows from table,

But there is some **error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token S in JSON at position 0`** and **also i don't want to display the server returned JSON on client side**. Instead this i want to display table and put values in that. I am attaching both `loadtable.js` and `search.php` code.

[image: See Error]

File `loadtable.js`

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var delay = 1000;

    // Campaign Submit Info
    $('[name="search_submit"]').click(function(e){ 

              e.preventDefault();

              var lead_status = $('#filterformpost').find('#lead_status_select option:selected').val();
              var campaign_status = $('#filterformpost').find('#campaign_status_select option:selected').val();
              var company_name = $('#filterformpost').find('#company_name_select option:selected').val();
              var tech_area = $('#filterformpost').find('#tech_area_select option:selected').val();
              var firm_size = $('#filterformpost').find('#firm_size_select option:selected').val();
              var firm_type = $('#filterformpost').find('#firm_type_select option:selected').val();
              var country_name = $('#filterformpost').find('#country_name_select option:selected').val();
              var state_name = $('#filterformpost').find('#state_name_select option:selected').val();
              var start_date = $('#filterformpost').find('#start_date_search').val();
              var end_date = $('#filterformpost').find('#end_date_search').val();

              console.log(lead_status)
              console.log(campaign_status)
              console.log(company_name)
              console.log(tech_area)
              console.log(firm_size)
              console.log(firm_type)
              console.log(country_name)
              console.log(state_name)
              console.log(start_date)
              console.log(end_date)

              $.ajax({
                       type: "POST",

                       url: "http://localhost/CRM/server/search.php",                        
                       data: {
                                "lead_status":lead_status, 
                                "campaign_status":campaign_status,
                                "company_name":company_name,
                                "tech_area":tech_area,
                                "firm_size":firm_size,
                                "firm_type":firm_type,
                                "country_name":country_name,
                                "state_name":state_name,
                                "start_date":start_date,
                                "end_date":end_date                          
                              },
                       beforeSend: function() {
                         $('.message_box').html(
                         '<img src="tenor.gif" width="40" height="40"/>'
                         );
                       }, 
                       success: function(data)
                       {
                       setTimeout(function() {
                       $('.message_box').html(data);
                       }, delay);
                       }                   

                    });                        


                  $.ajax({ 
                        method: "POST",      
                        url: "./server/search.php"

                      }).done(function( data ) { 

                        var result= $.parseJSON(data); 

                        var string='<table><thead><th>#</th><th>Lead ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Company</th><th>Location</th><th>Communication</th><th>Last Contact Date</th><th>Next Contact Date</th><th>Lead Status</th><th>Details</th></thead><tbody>';

                       /* from result create a string of data and append to the div */

                       var i = 1;

                        $.each( result, function( key, value ) { 

                                string += "<tr><td>"+i+"</td><td>"+value['Lead_Id']+"</td><td>"+value['FirstName']+' '+value['LastName']+"</td><td>"+value['Company']+"</td><td>"+value['State']+'\n'+value['Country']+"</td><td>"+value['Phone']+'\n'+value['Email']+"</td><td>"+value['LastContactDate']+"</td><td>"+value['NextContactDate']+"</td><td>"+value['LeadStatus']+"</td><td><a href='#'>Click Here</a></td></tr>";

                                i = i+1;

                              });          

                             string += '</tbody></table>'; 



                          $("#filterRecords").html(string);

                    });

            });


});
```

File `search.php`

```
<?php 

    include('connection.php');

    $sqlFlag = 0;

    function queryDelimiter(){
        global $sqlFlag;
        if ($sqlFlag == 0){
            $sqlFlag = 1;
            return ' WHERE ';
        }else{
            return ' AND ';
        }
    }

    $selectSQL = "SELECT * FROM tbl_main_lead_info";

    if(isset($_POST['lead_status']) and strlen(trim($_POST['lead_status'])) > 0){
        $selectSQL .= queryDelimiter()."LeadStatus = '".$_POST['lead_status']."'";
    }

    if(isset($_POST['company_name']) and strlen(trim($_POST['company_name'])) > 0){
        $selectSQL .= queryDelimiter()."Company = '".$_POST['company_name']."'";
    }       

    if(isset($_POST['tech_area']) and strlen(trim($_POST['tech_area'])) > 0){
        $selectSQL .= queryDelimiter()."TechArea = '".$_POST['tech_area']."'";
    }

    if(isset($_POST['firm_size']) and strlen(trim($_POST['firm_size'])) > 0){
        $selectSQL .= queryDelimiter()."FirmSize = '".$_POST['firm_size']."'";
    }

    if(isset($_POST['firm_type']) and strlen(trim($_POST['firm_type'])) > 0){
        $selectSQL .= queryDelimiter()."FirmType = '".$_POST['firm_type']."'";
    }

    if(isset($_POST['country_name']) and strlen(trim($_POST['country_name'])) > 0){
        $selectSQL .= queryDelimiter()."Country = '".$_POST['country_name']."'";
    }

    if(isset($_POST['state_name']) and strlen(trim($_POST['state_name'])) > 0){
        $selectSQL .= queryDelimiter()."State = '".$_POST['state_name']."'";
    }

    if(isset($_POST['start_date']) and strlen(trim($_POST['start_date'])) > 0){
        $selectSQL .= queryDelimiter()."LastContactDate >='".$_POST['start_date']."'";
    }

    if(isset($_POST['end_date']) and strlen(trim($_POST['end_date'])) > 0){
        $selectSQL .= queryDelimiter()."NextContactDate <= '".$_POST['end_date']."'";
    }

    $selectSQL .= " ORDER BY Lead_Id";  

    $result_array = array();

    $result = $conn -> query ($selectSQL);

    // If there are results from database push to result array

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

            array_push($result_array, $row);

        }

    }

    // send a JSON encoded array to client
    echo json_encode($result_array);

    $conn->close(); 

?>
```

In `dashboard.html` i have code as follows

```
 <!-- View Main Lead Table with Filters  -->
            <section class="operation" id="view_lead_info" style="display: none;">

                <!-- Filters -->

                <div class="row">                

                            <div class="col">
                                <label><p><b>Select Filter</b></p></label>                    
                            </div>          

                </div>


                <form action='' method='POST' class='filterformpost' id='filterformpost'>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col span-1-of-4">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col span-1-of-4">
                                    Lead Status:
                                </div>
                                <div class="col span-2-of-4">
                                    <select id='lead_status_select'><option value=''>Select</option>
                                        <?php
                                            echo "<option value='All'>All</option>";                                                
                                            echo "<option value='Active'>Active Leads</option>";
                                            echo "<option value='Paused'>Paused Leads</option>";
                                            echo "<option value='Expired'>Expired Leads</option>";
                                            echo "<option value='Unsubscribed'>Unsubscribed</option>";
                                        ?>                            
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>                         
                        </div>

                        <div class="col span-1-of-3">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col span-1-of-4">
                                    Campaign Status:
                                </div>
                                <div class="col span-2-of-4">
                                    <select id='campaign_status_select'><option value=''>Select</option>
                                        <?php     
                                            echo "<option value='All'>All</option>";                                           
                                            echo "<option value='Active'>Active</option>";
                                            echo "<option value='Paused'>Paused</option>";
                                            echo "<option value='Expired'>Expired</option>";
                                            echo "<option value='Unsubscribed'>Unsubscribed</option>";
                                        ?>                            
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>                        
                        </div>

                        <div class="col span-1-of-3">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col span-1-of-3">
                                    Company Name:
                                </div>
                                <div class="col span-2-of-3">                                       

                                        <?php                                            

                                            include('./server/connection.php');

                                            $sqlSelect="SELECT * FROM tbl_main_lead_info ORDER By Company ASC";
                                            $result = $conn -> query ($sqlSelect);                                                                                                                                  
                                            echo "<select id='company_name_select'>";
                                            echo "<option value=''>select</option>";    
                                            echo "<option value='All'>All</option>";                                        
                                            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                                                echo "<option value='$row[Company]'> $row[Company] </option>";
                                            }
                                            echo "</select>";

                                        ?>                          

                                </div>
                            </div>                        
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col span-1-of-4">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col span-1-of-4">
                                    State:
                                </div>
                                <div class="col span-2-of-4">                                       

                                        <?php                                            

                                            include('./server/connection.php');

                                            $sqlSelect="SELECT * FROM tbl_state_info ORDER By StateName ASC";
                                            $result = $conn -> query ($sqlSelect);                                           

                                            $result = $conn -> query ($sqlSelect);                                          

                                            echo "<select id='state_name_select' name='StateName'>";
                                            echo "<option value=''>select</option>";  
                                            echo "<option value='All'>All</option>";                                          
                                            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                                                echo "<option value='$row[StateName]'> $row[StateName] </option>";
                                            }
                                            echo "</select>";

                                        ?>                          

                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="col span-1-of-3">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col span-1-of-4">
                                    Country:
                                </div>
                                <div class="col span-2-of-4">
                                    <?php 

                                        include('./server/connection.php');

                                        $sqlSelect="SELECT * FROM tbl_country_info ORDER By CountryName ASC";
                                        $result = $conn -> query ($sqlSelect);                                         

                                        $result = $conn -> query ($sqlSelect);                                          

                                        echo "<select id='country_name_select' name='CountryName'>";
                                        echo "<option value=''>select</option>";
                                        echo "<option value='All'>All</option>";
                                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                                            echo "<option value='$row[CountryName]'> $row[CountryName] </option>";
                                        }
                                        echo "</select>";

                                    ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>                      
                        </div>

                        <div class="col span-1-of-3">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col span-1-of-3">
                                    Firm Type:
                                </div>
                                <div class="col span-2-of-3">
                                    <?php 

                                        include('./server/connection.php');

                                        $sqlSelect="SELECT * FROM tbl_firm_type_info ORDER By FirmType_Value ASC";
                                        $result = $conn -> query ($sqlSelect);                                    

                                        $result = $conn -> query ($sqlSelect);                                          

                                        echo "<select id='firm_type_select' name='FirmType'>";
                                        echo "<option value=''>select</option>";
                                        echo "<option value='All'>All</option>";
                                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                                            echo "<option value='$row[FirmType_Value]'> $row[FirmType_Value] </option>";
                                        }
                                        echo "</select>";

                                    ?>       
                                </div>
                            </div>                         
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col span-1-of-4">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col span-1-of-4">
                                    Firm Size:
                                </div>
                                <div class="col span-2-of-4">

                                    <?php 

                                        include('./server/connection.php');

                                        $sqlSelect="SELECT * FROM tbl_firm_size_info ORDER By FirmSize_Id ASC";
                                        $result = $conn -> query ($sqlSelect);                                         


                                        $result = $conn -> query ($sqlSelect);                                          


                                        echo "<select id='firm_size_select' name='FirmSize'>";
                                        echo "<option value=''>select</option>";
                                        echo "<option value='All'>All</option>";
                                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                                            echo "<option value='$row[FirmSize_Value]'> $row[FirmSize_Value] </option>";
                                        }
                                        echo "</select>";

                                    ?>

                                </div>
                            </div> 

                        </div>

                        <div class="col span-1-of-4">
                             <div class="row">
                                <div class="col span-1-of-3">
                                    Tech Area:
                                </div>
                                <div class="col span-2-of-3">
                                    <?php 

                                        include('./server/connection.php');

                                        $sqlSelect="SELECT * FROM tbl_tech_area_info ORDER By TechAreaName ASC";
                                        $result = $conn -> query ($sqlSelect);                                         


                                        $result = $conn -> query ($sqlSelect);                                          


                                        echo "<select id='tech_area_select' name='TechAreaName'>";
                                        echo "<option value=''>select</option>";
                                        echo "<option value='All'>All</option>";
                                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                                            echo "<option value='$row[TechAreaName]'> $row[TechAreaName] </option>";
                                        }
                                        echo "</select>";

                                    ?> 
                                </div>
                            </div>                          
                        </div>                

                        <div class="col span-1-of-4">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col span-1-of-4">
                                    Start Date:
                                </div>
                                <div class="col span-3-of-4">                          
                                        <?php 

                                        echo "<input type='date' id='start_date_search' name='startdate'>";

                                        ?>                                    
                                </div>
                            </div> 
                        </div>

                        <div class="col span-1-of-4">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col span-1-of-4">
                                    End Date:
                                </div>
                                <div class="col span-3-of-4">                            
                                        <?php 

                                        echo "<input type='date' id='end_date_search' name='enddate'>";

                                        ?>                                     
                                </div>
                            </div>                         
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="row">               

                        <div class="col span-1-of-3">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col span-3-of-4">

                                </div>               
                            </div> 
                        </div>    
                        <div class="col span-1-of-3">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col span-3-of-4">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col span-1-of-3">
                                            <label></label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col span-2-of-3">
                                            <input type="submit" name='search_submit' value="Search">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>                        
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </form>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col span-1-of-3">
                        <label></label>                            
                    </div>
                    <div class="col span-2-of-3">
                        <div class="message_box" style="margin-left: 60px;">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <div style="overflow-x:auto;">
                            <div id="filterRecords"></div> 
                        </div>                        
                    </div>                    
                </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Your query is vulnerable to SQL injections. Consider using [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

Comment: @Cid, will prepared SQL query can be used in Dynamic SQL?

Comment: Yes, but you will have to save somewhere the name of the parameter along with the value before binding stuff

Comment: Error: server returned JSON is empty but still in client side table displayed of search condition is displaying all table entries. Please solve it.

Comment: I attached all code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning more than just the desired json in your `search.php`

try removing these lines:

```
    echo $selectSQL;

    echo "<p></p>";
    echo "<p></p>";
```

for the json output in the frontend: you have 2 ajax calls in your js file, the first one puts the json into the div with the class `message_box`

for the results not changing: the results come from the 2nd ajax call, which does not send your form data.

try to change your js to this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var delay = 1000;

    // Campaign Submit Info
    $('[name="search_submit"]').click(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var lead_status = $('#filterformpost').find('#lead_status_select option:selected').val();
        var campaign_status = $('#filterformpost').find('#campaign_status_select option:selected').val();
        var company_name = $('#filterformpost').find('#company_name_select option:selected').val();
        var tech_area = $('#filterformpost').find('#tech_area_select option:selected').val();
        var firm_size = $('#filterformpost').find('#firm_size_select option:selected').val();
        var firm_type = $('#filterformpost').find('#firm_type_select option:selected').val();
        var country_name = $('#filterformpost').find('#country_name_select option:selected').val();
        var state_name = $('#filterformpost').find('#state_name_select option:selected').val();
        var start_date = $('#filterformpost').find('#start_date_search').val();
        var end_date = $('#filterformpost').find('#end_date_search').val();

        console.log(lead_status)
        console.log(campaign_status)
        console.log(company_name)
        console.log(tech_area)
        console.log(firm_size)
        console.log(firm_type)
        console.log(country_name)
        console.log(state_name)
        console.log(start_date)
        console.log(end_date)

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            // url: "https://tribalyze.com/CRM/server/login.php",
            url: "search.php",
            data: {
                "lead_status": lead_status,
                "campaign_status": campaign_status,
                "company_name": company_name,
                "tech_area": tech_area,
                "firm_size": firm_size,
                "firm_type": firm_type,
                "country_name": country_name,
                "state_name": state_name,
                "start_date": start_date,
                "end_date": end_date
            },
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('.message_box').html(
                    '<img src="tenor.gif" width="40" height="40"/>'
                );
            },
            success: function(data) {
                var result = $.parseJSON(data);

                var string = '<table><thead><th>#</th><th>Lead ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Company</th><th>Location</th><th>Communication</th><th>Last Contact Date</th><th>Next Contact Date</th><th>Lead Status</th><th>Details</th></thead><tbody>';

                /* from result create a string of data and append to the div */

                var i = 1;

                $.each(result, function(key, value) {

                    string += "<tr><td>" + i + "</td><td>" + value['Lead_Id'] + "</td><td>" + value['FirstName'] + ' ' + value['LastName'] + "</td><td>" + value['Company'] + "</td><td>" + value['State'] + '\n' + value['Country'] + "</td><td>" + value['Phone'] + '\n' + value['Email'] + "</td><td>" + value['LastContactDate'] + "</td><td>" + value['NextContactDate'] + "</td><td>" + value['LeadStatus'] + "</td><td><a href='#'>Click Here</a></td></tr>";

                    i = i + 1;

                });

                string += '</tbody></table>';



                $("#filterRecords").html(string);
                $('.message_box').html('');
            }

        });

    });


});
```

Comment: Right - but also remove the 2 `echo "<p></p>";` the "S" at position 0 of your error message is the first letter of your query that you write to the output "SELECT..."

Comment: yes that red console error gone away thanks but when once table is displayed based on searched condition it remains there inspite of change condition and also the server returned JSON is also displayed there in client side.

Comment: Actually i think my search SQL query is not working please see into it.

Comment: you do make 2 ajax calls in your javascript: the first writes the JSON into the elment with the class "message_box" - that's why you see the JSON on the client side. as for the table not beeing updated, i would need to see the html file to check that (or as you said it may be the query not working)

Comment: Also: you use the form input directly in the query - this makes it vulnerable to sql injection - try using [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: can i post html code also it is nothing just a `div` tag with `id='filterRecords'`

Comment: you could add the html code to the question - but if it's only a `div` with the id, it won't be necessary - does the query return any results?

Comment: i attached `dashboard.html` code part. please see, also i am not aware about the prepared SQL statement.

Comment: Can removing this `e.preventDefault()` helps in reloading table based on the search condition?

Comment: It is returning a JSON which i am parsing and displaying in filter table but display of table is not changes when i again click on search button. also my SQL query is modified on `Search` button click and is executing correctly. But don't know why the table is not modified by new search condition.

Comment: Also why server JSON is displayed on client side

Comment: see my edited answer for the json output & the results not changing

Comment: Yes it worked now correctly but there is slight changes i think needed in solution, i.e. after displaying table my GIF is still rotating. It need to stop rotate on display of table or hide. That i solve using ` $('.message_box').hide();`

Comment: that would work - but you would have to show it again on the next search - try                     `$('.message_box').html('');` instead (i updated my answer accordingly)